# Having trouble making a converter

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a very simple kilograms to pounds converter in c#. To do this, I wish to read the user's number, times it by 2.2, store it as a variable and then print the result.
However, I am getting an error on the line where I times it by 2.2 saying "operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' or 'double'". I cannot really see what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //this application will convert kilograms to pounds
        string kiloAmount;
        Console.WriteLine("Type the number of pounds:");
        kiloAmount = Console.ReadLine();
        Convert.ToDouble(kiloAmount);
        double poundsAmount = kiloAmount * 2.2;
        Console.WriteLine(kiloAmount);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, just realised that should say number of kilos, not pounds.

Comment: You can [edit] your question if you wish to change things or provide more information etc

Answer (score 4):

`Convert.ToDouble` *returns* the value converted to double. It cannot convert the argument (for various reasons - you'll encounter those over time). You're trying to multiply the original value, which is a `string`, not a number.

Instead, do this:

```
var poundsString = Console.ReadLine();
var pounds = Convert.ToDouble(poundsString);

var kilos = pounds * 2.2;
```

Also, it might be a better idea to use `double.TryParse`, so that you can handle invalid inputs gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

Kilo amount is not assigned anywhere as double:

```
double newKiloAmount = Convert.ToDouble(kiloAmount);
```